# How to use Azure Key Vault from Azure Functions (v2)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am tring to use Azure Key Vault from Azure Functions (v2);
When I run local it works, but when I publish this code to Azure:

```
try
{
    var vault_url = "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/";
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback), client);

    fbAppSecret = (await kvClient.GetSecretAsync(vault_url, "facebook-appid-secret-...")).Value;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    error = ex.ToString();
}
```

It is giving an Exception that contains this (Please check that you are running on an Azure resource that has MSI setup.):

```
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connectionstring: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/66ad737e-d8cc-4ab3-abf0-feab50685d13. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connectionstring: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/66ad737e-d8cc-4ab3-abf0-feab50685d13. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Unable to connect to the Managed Service Identity (MSI) endpoint. Please check that you are running on an Azure resource that has MSI setup.
Parameters: Connectionstring: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/66ad737e-d8cc-4ab3-abf0-feab50685d13. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not found at "D:\local\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json"
Parameters: Connectionstring: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/66ad737e-d8cc-4ab3-abf0-feab50685d13. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.<GetAccessTokenAsyncImpl>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.<PostAuthenticate>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.<ProcessHttpRequestAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__65.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.<GetSecretAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ApelosUrgentesFunctionApp.MyFunctions.<Run>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\tonyv\source\repos\siteApelosUrgentes\ApelosUrgentesFunctionApp\MyFunctions.cs:line 50
```

Then I found
MSI means Managed Service identity and can be enabled on the Azure Functions Portal:

[image: Managed Service Identity]

But after enabled it, there is another Exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Access denied
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__65.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.<GetSecretAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ApelosUrgentesFunctionApp.MyFunctions.<Run>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\tonyv\source\repos\siteApelosUrgentes\ApelosUrgentesFunctionApp\MyFunctions.cs:line 50
```

I added the Azure Functions App as Reader, then later as Owner, but still getting

I added the Azure Functions App as Owner, but still getting

```
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Access denied
at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__65.MoveNext()
```

[image: IAM]

I also added all the access policies, but still getting Access Denied

[image: AP]
[image: AP2]

Checked Kudu, AppSettings:

https://myfunctionapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings

```
{"deployment_branch":"master","SCM_TRACE_LEVEL":"1","SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT":"60","SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT":"1800","SCM_BUILD_ARGS":"","aspnet:PortableCompilationOutput":"true","aspnet:PortableCompilationOutputSnapshotType":"Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots.SnapshotHelper, Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","aspnet:DisableFcnDaclRead":"true","SCM_GIT_USERNAME":"windowsazure","SCM_GIT_EMAIL":"windowsazure","webpages:Version":"3.0.0.0","webpages:Enabled":"true","webactivator:assembliesToScan":"Kudu.Services.Web","MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES":"1","FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION":"beta","ScmType":"None","WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED":"False","REMOTEDEBUGGINGVERSION":"15.0.26730.8","WEBSITE_DISABLE_MSI":"false","AzureWebJobsDashboard":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=functionapp;AccountKey=xQ","WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=functionapp;AccountKey=xq","WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE":"apelosurgentesfunctionapp","WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME":"Production","AzureWebJobsStorage":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=functionapp;AccountKey=xq","WEBSITE_SITE_NAME":"FunctionApp"}
```

**How to solve this?**

Comment: I also posted on MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab8222b4-1859-4250-ae6f-e813b04a6e31/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-from-azure-functions-v2?forum=AzureKeyVault

Comment: HI Tony, I'm pretty sure the steps outlined here, are right up your alley. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity?WT.mc_id=docs-twitter-scottca#creating-an-app-with-an-identity

Comment: Why does it works out of the box on localhost, but on published version I have to follow all those steps?

Comment: See also: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/06/13/how-to-connect-to-a-database-from-an-azure-function-using-azure-key-vault/?utm_source=jeliknes&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=link&WT.mc_id=link-twitter-jeliknes

Answer (score 2):

One detail I found in your pictures is in Access Policies, you have "application + application" under your Service Principal.

Are you able to remove the service principal and add it back with only the app in the Service Principal, leaving Authorized App blank

As seen in this Article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault#authentication-using-azure-active-directory

When you use the authorized applications is for apps that must access on behalf of signed in users, thus An application working on behalf of itself does not works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it works out of the box on localhost, but on published version I have to follow all those steps?

You could refer to [Azure Services Authentication Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrismann.MicrosoftVisualStudioAsalExtension) to get more information about how it works on the localhost. It use the your login account and your account has the access to the Azure key vault resource.

[image]

If you publish it to Azure function, you could use the Azure MSI function, it will registry the Azure AD application automatically.Then we also need to assgin the permisson to access the KeyVault.

I also test it on my side,it works correctly. Please make sure that MSI is enabled correctly in your case. You could check the **MSI_SECRET** and **MSI_ENDPOINT** with Azure kudu tool.

Comment: I enabled MSI, (disabled, and reenabled, but did not work yet) Checked Kudu, https://myfunctionapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings   there is no MSI_SECRET, nor MSI_ENDPOINT

Comment: Did you test it on using Azure Functions v2?

Comment: Yes, I test it with Azure function V2

Comment: If there is no  MSI_SECRET or  MSI_SECRET it means that MSI doesn't enable correctly.

Comment: Have you tried a manual site restart? That may help resolve it. The enablement gesture is supposed to restart the site and add these settings, but something may have gone wrong there. The process is repeated on site restarts, generally, so a manual restart may help.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the AzureServiceTokenProvider's *PrincipalUsed* property to check what *AppId* is being used to authenticate, or in other words, what is the Managed Service Identity being used. The fact that you are getting "Access Denied" means that it was possible to get the access token, but the MSI does not have access to Key Vault. You did grant access to a service principal, but most likely, not to the right one. Use the *AppId* returned in *PrincipalUsed* to search for "Service Principal" using Key Vault "Access Policy".

Comment: I will check that, and tell here later.

Answer (score 0):

This is the current easy way with Azure Functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

e.g. specific version `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)`

e.g. get latest version (note: trailing slash!)
`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)`

Comment: Will this work locally(config in local.settings.json)?